# Adding an dynamic object to a grid programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, object, grid

So this has been bugging the hell out of me for a few days now and can't seem to figure out a way to do this.

This is what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

[image]

On button click of "Add server" I would like the program to create a object that contains the information of the fields in the flyout.

The user is then able to click on one of those objects to connect to his server and do what ever task is needed at that point.

If anyone could help with this issue it would be a massive help.

Comment: do you have a data model for the same? is is possible for you to share a working sample?

Comment: If that was aimed at me then no, sorry, i do not have a working example that i can provide you with.

Answer (score 0):

You need your panel in the code to manipulate it. Maybe you can execute an command on loading the panel and send it to your vm via commandparameter.

Then on "add server" command executed you add your new configured control to the panel like this quick solution in code behind (on a click): this.MyGridPanel.Children.Add(new Button());

If you have a grid and you use columns and rows, you can set viw 
Button btn = new Button();
btn.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 3);